# Best practice for comparing two large files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to **compare two large files**(5GB+) and find if they are the same or not. One solution I considered is **hashing both** with crypto and then comparing the hashes. But this would take a lot of time since I will have to go through the entire files instead of stopping when a difference is found. 
Another solution I thought was to compare the file as they are being streamed with `fs.createReadStream()` and break when a difference is found.

```
stream.on('data', (data) => {
   //compare the data from this stream with the other stream
})
```

But I am not quite sure how I can have two streams that are synchronized.

Comment: First check if they have the same size. If the size is different, then logically they re different. If the size is *exactly* the same, then you need to analyse further. You can sample few random equal sections from both to check for equality - that's still going to be fairly cheap. *Then* you might choose to hash them. I'd expect a library can handle this for you but I don't know of any.

Comment: First check for matching file sizes.  Then, just read each file in 1k blocks (probably using promises) and compare those two buffers.  Put this in a loop and break the loop when you find a difference.  This will be cheaper than hashing each both because you get to break as soon as a difference is found and second because you don't have to calculate the hash for each.  Comparing two buffers with `buffer.compare()` should be really fast and optimized.

Comment: @jfriend00 that is sort of what I thought problem is am not sure to _actually_ do it. Could you share some code please. Thanks.

Comment: @RafGk_ - Per your request, I added an answer with code to implement the scheme I described earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As requested in your comments, if you want to see how an implementation can be written to do this, here's one.  Here's how it works:

1. Open each of the two files
2. Compare the two files sizes.  If not the same, resolve false.
3. Allocate two 8k buffers (you can choose the size of buffer to use)
4. Read 8k of each file (or less if not 8k left in the file) into your buffers
5. Compare those two buffers.  If not identical, resolve false.
6. When you finish comparing all the bytes, resolve true

Here's the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

// resolves to true or false
async function compareFiles(fname1, fname2) {
    const kReadSize = 1024 * 8;
    let h1, h2;
    try {
        h1 = await fsp.open(fname1);
        h2 = await fsp.open(fname2);
        const [stat1, stat2] = await Promise.all([h1.stat(), h2.stat()]);
        if (stat1.size !== stat2.size) {
            return false;
        }
        const buf1 = Buffer.alloc(kReadSize);
        const buf2 = Buffer.alloc(kReadSize);
        let pos = 0;
        let remainingSize = stat1.size;
        while (remainingSize > 0) {
            let readSize = Math.min(kReadSize, remainingSize);
            let [r1, r2] = await Promise.all([h1.read(buf1, 0, readSize, pos), h2.read(buf2, 0, readSize, pos)]);
            if (r1.bytesRead !== readSize || r2.bytesRead !== readSize) {
                throw new Error("Failed to read desired number of bytes");
            }
            if (buf1.compare(buf2, 0, readSize, 0, readSize) !== 0) {
                return false;
            }
            remainingSize -= readSize;
            pos += readSize;
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (h1) {
            await h1.close();
        }
        if (h2) {
            await h2.close();
        }
    }
}

// sample usage
compareFiles("temp.bin", "temp2.bin").then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This could be sped up a bit by opening and closing the files in parallel using `Promise.allSettled()` to track when they are both open and then both closed, though because of the complications if one succeeds in opening and the other doesn't and you don't want to leak the one opened file handle, it takes a bit more code to do that perfectly so I kept it simpler here.

And, if you really wanted to optimize for performance, it would be worth testing larger buffers to see if it makes things faster or not.

It's also possible that `buf1.equals(buf2)` might be faster than `buf1.compare(buf2)`, but you have to make sure that a partial buffer read at the end of the file still works properly when using that since `.equals()` always compares the entire buffer.  You could build two versions and compare their performance.

---

Here's a more complicated version that opens and closes the files in parallel and might be slightly faster:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

async function compareFiles(fname1, fname2) {
    const kReadSize = 1024 * 8;
    let h1, h2;
    try {
        let openResults = await Promise.allSettled([fsp.open(fname1), fsp.open(fname2)]);
        let err;
        if (openResults[0].status === "fulfilled") {
            h1 = openResults[0].value;
        } else {
            err = openResults[0].reason;
        }
        if (openResults[1].status === "fulfilled") {
            h2 = openResults[1].value;
        } else {
            err = openResults[1].reason;
        }
        // after h1 and h2 are set (so they can be properly closed)
        // throw any error we got
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        const [stat1, stat2] = await Promise.all([h1.stat(), h2.stat()]);
        if (stat1.size !== stat2.size) {
            return false;
        }
        const buf1 = Buffer.alloc(kReadSize);
        const buf2 = Buffer.alloc(kReadSize);
        let pos = 0;
        let remainingSize = stat1.size;
        while (remainingSize > 0) {
            let readSize = Math.min(kReadSize, remainingSize);
            let [r1, r2] = await Promise.all([h1.read(buf1, 0, readSize, pos), h2.read(buf2, 0, readSize, pos)]);
            if (r1.bytesRead !== readSize || r2.bytesRead !== readSize) {
                throw new Error("Failed to read desired number of bytes");
            }
            if (buf1.compare(buf2, 0, readSize, 0, readSize) !== 0) {
                return false;
            }
            remainingSize -= readSize;
            pos += readSize;
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        // does not return file close errors
        // but does hold resolving the promise until the files are closed
        // or had an error trying to close them
        // Since we didn't write to the files, a close error would be fairly 
        // unprecedented unless the disk went down
        const closePromises = [];
        if (h1) {
            closePromises.push(h1.close());
        }
        if (h2) {
            closePromises.push(h2.close());
        }
        await Promise.allSettled(closePromises);
    }
}

compareFiles("temp.bin", "temp2.bin").then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: @RafGk_ - I added another version that might be slightly faster (opens and closes the two files in parallel instead of serially).

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly libraries that do this, and [file-sync-cmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-sync-cmp) is very popular (270k weekly downloads). It does the comparison in [the simplest way](https://github.com/mgeisler/file-sync-cmp/blob/master/index.js), by reading the same number of bytes from the two files in different buffers, and then comparing the buffers byte by byte.

There's also a more modern library, [filecompare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filecompare), "using native Promises and native BufferTools (alloc and Buffer comparisons)".

Whenever practical, don't reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference might be at the very end of the files, I guess calculating a hash of the files is the most (yet costly) straightforward and secure process.

Did you try the [MD5-File](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5-file) npm package and get some performance indicators?

Comment: I use the built in crypto module that supports most algorithms including md5. I just tested hashing the windows10 iso (6.2GB) and got results ranging from 24 to 33 seconds. Considering I want to compare two files this would take about 1 minute.

Comment: Well, that's what asynchronous programming is about. If you CPU is not fully used by one hash computation, you may start the two hashes in parallel and use a good old `Promise.all()` to process the follow up actions.